# What does stub.callsArg(index) from Sinon.JS do?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

Seriously, I can't figure this out. The documentation gives us:

**stub.callsArg(index)** - Causes the stub to call the argument at the provided index as a callback function. stub.callsArg(0); causes the stub to call the first argument as a callback.

However, I've got no idea where this list of arguments to be indexed into is. Maybe I just don't understand what a stub is...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A stub is a noop function with programmable behavior. In your case `callsArg(index)` will program the stub to expect a function at `index` and immediately invoke it.

```
function sayHi() {
  console.log('hi');
}
var stub = sinon.stub().callsArg(2);
stub('abc', 42, sayHi); // prints "hi"
```

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. What is the point of calling `stub()` in a test directly? Does it really call something or it's configuring it?